# Moving window between monitors when using multiple desktops

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

The following script moves window from my left monitor to the right monitor (2560x1440 each)

```
win = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
winPlacement = list(win32gui.GetWindowPlacement(win))

left, top, right, bottom = winPlacement[4]
winPlacement[4] = (left + 2560, top, right + 2560, bottom)
  
win32gui.SetWindowPlacement(win, winPlacement)
```

At first glance, the function is working fine - window is moved to the same spot but on the right monitor. It stays in this position as long as I am on the same desktop.

But when I switch to another desktop (CTRL + WIN + →) and return back (CTRL + WIN + ←) the window is back on it's original position. I tried to use function `MoveWindow` but it behaves the same. This problem is not present when the window is moved withing the bounds of the same monitor.

It seems like windows is storing this old position somewhere and applying it back every time I switch to another desktop. Is this a bug or do I have to do something else to make this new position permament?

Comment: Why are you using `[Get|Set]WindowPlacement()` instead of using `GetWindowRect()`+`SetWindowPos()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau No specific reason, those were just the first methods I found. Just tried to move it with`win32gui.SetWindowPos(win, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, left + 2560, top, right - left, bottom - top, 0)`  but it has the same problem as `SetWindowPlacement` when switching desktops.

Comment: You probably need to use [`IVirtualDesktopManager::MoveWindowToDesktop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager-movewindowtodesktop) to actually move your window into the target desktop, not just position the window over the desktop.